# Fill in a input field on a website with JavaScript if it has no id?

Tags: javascript, html, input, getelementbyid, autofill

How can I fill in a input field on a website with JavaScript if it has no id? Example:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First Name" value="" class="someclass">
<input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" value="" class="someclass">
```

I only want to fill in the first input field.

If it had an ID I could just do `document.getElementById`...
the class and type are used by several input fields on the website. Could I maybe use the placeholder somehow?

Comment: .someclass -> item 0 -> value

Comment: IDs aren't the only way to select an element. You can do it by class, position in the DOM, and more. See `querySelector`

Comment: `document.querySelector('.someclasss')` or `document.getElementsByClassName('someclass')`

Comment: @PrakashReddyPotlapadu but how will it know which specific field to use? As I stated, there are several input fields on the website using the same class

Comment: You have to select them all based on the class and use the index for the correction position (element).

Comment: @EternalHour could you maybe give me a specific example on how to do this or a link where I can read up on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply select it with `document.querySelector('input.someclass')`

## EDIT

If the order and amount of inputs is always the same on your website just do this:

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')
```

You can choose the input from the array that querySelectorAll returns or loop through the array to input the values.

```
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
const valuesToInput = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i += 1) {
   inputs[i].value = valuesToInput[i];
}
```

Comment: but how will it know which specific field to use? As I stated, there are several input fields on the website using the same class

Comment: I assume you can't change or add anything else to it right? How many inputs are there on the site you want to fill the specific one? Is the number or order of the inputs is changing?

Comment: There are 9 input fields. I want to fill all of them, but with a different value each. No, number or order aren't changing.

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: No problem :) Added the loop to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you add the property "name" for you form and input, you can use that with the following way:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" name="myText">
    <button onclick="addText(myForm)">Add Text</button>
</form>
```

in javascript:

```
function addText(myForm){
    myForm.myText.value = 'some text';
}
```